# Transfer a file/directory from local computer to remote computer via SSH in C?

Tags: c, ssh

I have my local computer and I also have a remote computer. I want to make a C program that moves a file or folder to that remote computer. How can I do this in C? Or is this only possible though Terminal commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how complex your requirements are, you could use [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/) (LGPL, used in various ssh clients), investigate modifying [dropbear](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) (MIT), or quick 'n dirty:

```
system("scp myfile host:/some/path/to/file");
```